# In VBA, I want to make an If statement for when more than one cell in a range contains a value

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the following VBA loop set up, but want to add a line that says "If there are two cells within this range that have a value, do this. If there are three cells within a range that have a value, do that." What I have so far is:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    While i <= 133
        Set Rng = Range("C" & i)

        If Rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7) <> "" Then
            Rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Blank"
            i = i + 1
        Else: Stop
        End If
    Wend


End Sub
```

So I have the VBA script print the word "Blank" into the appropriate cell if this range is empty. But how can I add more lines to say "If one cell in this range contains a value," or "if two cells in this range contain a value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can check if there are more than one non-empty cell in the given range:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7)) > 1 Then
```

---

Few additional tips to your code:

- If you know exactly the initial and final value of `i` you should use `For ... Next` loop instead of `While ... Wend`. So you could replace this code:

  ```
  i = 3
  '(...)

  While i <= 133
      '(...)
      i = i + 1

  Wend
  ```

  with this:

  ```
  For i = 3 To 133
      '(...)
  Next i
  ```
- I think this line of code will cause **Type mismatch** error:

  ```
  If Rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7) <> "" Then
  ```

  because you are trying to compare an object of `Range` type with a primitive value (empty string). To avoid this issue you can use the similar code as above:

  ```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7)) = 0 Then
  ```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you might like to add code along these lines

```
Select case  Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7))
      case 0
          Rng.Offset(, 1).value = "Blank"
      case 1
          Rng.Offset(, 1).value = "Only One"
      case >2
          Rng.Offset(, 1).value = "More than 1"
end select
```